# Consider sign in ytick label adjustment

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

When adding a colorbar to images plotting with `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`, the colorbar's tick labels are normally placed to the right. If the value range spans positive and negative values, this leads to a misalignment between positive and negative values (positive values do not account for the '-' sign), which, IMHO, is very ugly.

How can I adjust this so that the tick labels are aligned properly?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(100, 100) - 0.5

plt.figure(figsize=(2,1.5))
img = plt.imshow(data)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the positive and negative labels on the colorbar aligned, you may align the text to the right and increase the padding between axis and labels. The amount of padding to add will depend on the length of the ticklabels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(100, 100) - 0.5

plt.figure()
img = plt.imshow(data)
cbar = plt.colorbar()

plt.setp(cbar.ax.get_yticklabels(), ha="right")
cbar.ax.tick_params(pad=30)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm not convinced that this looks better though.

Comment: Well, looks are subjective, but this is what I was looking for. Any chance to set this once for all plots, e.g. similar to `rcParams`?

Comment: The problem is that any global setting via `rcParams` would affect *all* y ticklabels, i.e. also those on the image plot.

Comment: I have was hoping for something that only affects labels on the right side of an axis... But I see, this is likely not supported.

Comment: The full list of rcParams is available [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file), if you want to play around with them. But I can already tell you now that there is no side-specific alignment or padding available.

Comment: There is none. I looked into rcParams before posting this question.